# Two axiom systems are equipollent if...?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, foundations

I'm reading "Introduction to Logic: And to the Methodology of Deductive Sciences by Tarski", and in this book he first created an axiom system called A, which contains some superfluous axioms (axioms that can be derived from other axioms of the same axiom system), then he got rid of these superfluous axioms and called the new axiom system A¹, then he got rid of all superfluous primitive terms (expressions that seems immediately understandable, like "a set" or the relation "<") and called this new axiom system A².

Then he says: "One can find many axiom systems which are equipollent" specifying: "in this chapter equipollence will ordinarily refer to means of proof" and he gives an example of a new axiom system A³, in which all the axioms are contained in the system A (which means some axioms in system A and A³ are the same) or have been proved on its basis (which means, some theorems that were proved from the axioms of A are now axioms), and since system A and A² are equipollent all the sentences of A³ can also be proved on the bases of A².

Now finally my problem, he says: "Just as in the case of axioms, one can find systems of primitive terms which are equipollent to a given system. This applies, in particular, to the system of the three terms ℝ, <, and + (A³ is a system with only these primitive terms). If, for instance, we replace < by the symbol ≤ we obtain an equipollent system"

One of the axioms of the system A³ states  "If x < y, then y≮x" but if I replace < by the symbol ≤ I would get "If x≤y, then y≰x" which is false (when x=y). So how can A³ and this new axiom system be equipollent? What am I missing? What is exactly the definition of equipollent axiom system since he doesn't give any? maybe "two axiom systems A and B are equipollent if all the axioms of A are contained in the system B or have been proved on its basis (or vice versa)"?

Thank you!

Comment: If the answer below is satisfying for you, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The new axioms don't need to be identical. If you introduce another symbol (eg $\leqslant$ instead of $<$), it has another meaning and you have to restate axioms accordingly. eg the antisymmetry would be stated with this axiom :
$$ \forall x \  \forall y \ (x \leqslant y \wedge y \leqslant x) \Rightarrow x = y$$

Comment: So, if I replace those symbols and get some of my axioms to not be valid anymore I can just "remove them" and nothing would happen. Two axiom systems are equipollent if I can prove with both the same things right?

Comment: If you replace your symbols you can't use the old symbols anymore to state an axiom.

Comment: yeah yeah I know, i'm saying I can remove the axioms that would not result valid after the symbol replacement and replace them with new ones that state the same thing but with the new symbol and keep the axioms that would result valid after the same transformation correct? but why are the two axiom systems equipollent?? because both can prove the same things?

Comment: Basically yes : they describe the same universe.  By this it is meant that, in any model of the axioms of one system :

1. Each symbol of the other system can be defined using symbols of this system.

2. The statements proven within this model using these definitions, Are precisely those that can be deduced from the other system.

Comment: I found it, the definition was given in a preceding chapter: "Call two systems of sentences of a given theory equipollent, if each sentence of the first system can be derived from the sentences of the second, together with theorems of any theories which precede the given theory, and, conversely, if every sentence of the second system can be derived from the sentences of the first (together with theorems of any preceding theories)".

Comment: But I still dont understand why he didn't explained that one has to restate the axioms.. he just said "if we replace the symbol "<" by the symbol "≤", we obtain an equipollent system; for the second of these symbols was defined in terms of the first, and the first may be defined by means of the second."
and the law "x<y, then y≮x" is not the law of antisymmetry, it's the law of asymmetry, and as Wikipedia says: "The relation ≤, is not asymmetric" so i don' get how one can express this law using the ≤ relation.. but thank you anway

Comment: From the definition you quoted above, it seems that the situation is as follows :
  System 1 is in language $L_1$, system 2 is in language $L_2$, but we see the whole in a model of some $L$-theory where $L \supseteq L_1 \cup L_2$. eg in the example the ambient structure would be $(\mathbb{R}, +, <, \leqslant)$.